# Bluetooth cannot be turned on after booting

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth doesn't work until the device is set to airplane mode and then going into power option and enabling WiFi from there. This needs to be done on 20.10 and on 20.04 LTS to turn on bluetooth the bluetooth and WiFi hardware need to be disabled and enabled again.This needs to be done after every start of the laptop Pavillion g6 1007sx even after the suspend mode .How to solve this permanently?

..........................................................................

Edited-
using hciconffig -a after starting my laptop I get this message
hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
DOWN
RX bytes:34 acl:0 sco:0 events:3 errors:0
TX bytes:12 acl:0 sco:0 commands:4 errors:0
Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0x9b 0xff 0x79 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
Link policy:
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT

..........................................................................

and after disabling the bluetooth and WiFi hardware and re enabling it,
I get this message:

```
hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: CC:52:AF:21:82:5C  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN 
    RX bytes:650 acl:0 sco:0 events:46 errors:0
    TX bytes:4285 acl:0 sco:0 commands:46 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0x9b 0xff 0x79 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'Asad'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 3.0 (0x5)  Revision: 0x1e1
    LMP Version: 3.0 (0x5)  Subversion: 0x4203
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)
```

Comment: This is a common problem in kernel version <5.7. Which kernel are you currently running (`uname -r`)? Might be related to this common issue with Bluetooth devices.

Comment: 5.8.0-43-generic

Comment: Thought it was worth asking, since version 5.7 solved a lot of issues with bluetooth hardware

Comment: is there a fix by editing files... or by giving the bluetooth model number